# HTML5 not caching when internet is online

Tags: javascript, php, html, caching

Here i'm planning to build a **HTML5 mobile app with offline reading mechanism.**

I have some dynamic content in one page which i need to show in both when internet is there or not.

I'm using the **caching** mechanism by **manifest**.

The first time time when i load the dynamic page when online it is cached and when in internet goes offline i'm also able to see the dynamic page.

But the problem is when again the internet connection comes back shouldn't the dynamic page should be called again?. But that is not happening.

I tried  to put an .htaccess file for mozilla firefox said in this blog http://html5doctor.com/go-offline-with-application-cache/

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

I have gone through many blogs and site for this purpose For ex:- https://www.sitepoint.com/common-pitfalls-avoid-using-html5-application-cache/ .

Nothings happening !!!

My pages are:

1) home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="dtt.appcache">
<body>

<p><button onClick="loadDoc(1)" type="button">home</button> || <button onClick="loadDoc(2)" type="button">centers</button> || <button onClick="loadDoc(3)" type="button">about us</button></p>

<!--<p><a href="home.html" >home</a> || <a href="centers.php" >centers</a> || <a href="about-us.html" >about us</a></p>-->

<div id="contentarea">
This is my home page.
</div>

 <script>

    function loadDoc(id) {

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("contentarea").innerHTML =
          this.responseText;
        }
      };

    if(id == '1'){
         document.getElementById("contentarea").innerHTML =
          'This is my home page'
    } else if(id=='2'){


      xhttp.open("GET", "centers.php", true);
      xhttp.send();
  }else if(id=='3'){
  document.getElementById("contentarea").innerHTML =
          'This is my about us page'
  }
}
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

2) centers.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="dtt.appcache">
<body>
<?php echo time().'<br>';?>
</body>
</html>
```

3) dtt.appcache

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2003-12-01 v2.0.0
home.html
centers.php
about-us.html
```

My requirement is as simple as if internet connectivity is there pages should be cached for offline reading(which is happening) and if internet connectivity is there every time it should read from that dynamic content page.

Answer (score 0):

Actually **Application cache** feature is now **deprecated**. so most of the browsers wont support fully.
instead of this you can use **cache storage feature using service workers**. it is supported chrome browser as well.

Comment: Could you give a go how i can use service worker for my above example.

Comment: right now i don't have any working sample ready. but you may get idea from below link.

Comment: https://mobiforge.com/design-development/taking-web-offline-service-workers

Comment: For using service workers an https is required :https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers